# Problem with adding additional attributes to the button in Wordpress editor

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a problem with adding extra attributes to the button. I want to add this attribute to the button:

`onclick=currentDiv(1, 'color')`

but in reality when i submit the changes and check it in the code i get `onclick=currentDiv(1," &#039;color&#039;)` instead. Im using avada theme editor and avada button.

I tried to make a code block and create a simple html button `<button onclick="currentDiv(1, 'color')">Color 1</button>`and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

I checked the documentation for the Avada button, and it doens't explicity say you can't add an onclick attribute, but in the example of attributes you can add it gives:  rel='nofollow'.  Based on that, and the fact that it is clearly HTML-encoding the apostrophes, I'd say you need another method to listen for the click event on this button.

So what I would do here, is give the button a unique CSS Class (different from any class used in the whole site, so something like "eksport-currentdiv".  Next, add some custom javascript.  You can add this into the page with Avada's "Code Block" element.  This should do what you want:

```
<script>
(function($){
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.eksport-currentdiv').on('click', function(){
         currentDiv(1, 'color')
      });
   });
})(jQuery);
<script>
```